"One thing I know about Experts" - identify this movie
I have this dialog in my mind, but I cannot remember this movie.

One thing I know about experts is that they are experts on f**k all.

Its probably a dialog of Jason Stathom but I don't know for sure.
Anybody know this movie?

With some googling I found out that this quote is from the movie Revolver (2005).
I found this page which includes the quote you mention:

The dialogue is at times so strange I was genuinely left wondering if
  it was meant to be funny. Statham says “bastard” more times than I
  could count. Lines from his voiceover include “they’re smart. Smart as
  a pair of little boy’s shoes”, “it’s a dangerous combination, chess
  and cons” and “if there’s one thing I’ve learnt about experts, it’s
  that they’re experts on fuck all.” These are just the ones I managed
  to jot down, but almost every line of Statham’s dialogue has this
  quality to it. It all has the air of something that’s supposed to
  sound profound or sincere but is so woefully misjudged as to be
  completely laughable.


Thanks I was searching "One thing I know about experts is that they are experts on" and it did not provide any useful link.

Np, you should have left the "f**k all" (without the *'s) in. It was the first link that popped up^^

ha ha my bad ;)
